# Pasar a mayusculas y minusculas una cadena java

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un programa que reciba una cadena y devuelva la misma cadena, intercalando mayúsculas y minúsculas, es decir reciba hola mundo (da igual mayúsculas y minúsculas) y escriba HoLa MuNdO, sin tener en cuenta los espacios. Ahora lo que me hace es HoLa mUnDo, tiene en cuenta los espacios. El código que tengo es, utilizando ascii, sin comandos de esos que te lo hacen directamente.

Luego otra pregunta que tengo es como conseguir hacer estos otros dos programas: HolA MundO que pase a mayúscula o minúscula según la entrada la primera y ultima letra y la otra Hola Mundo, solo las primeras letras de la palabra, al introducir por teclado una cadena.

```
import java.util.*;

public class amayus {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Escriba una cadena");
    String cad = teclado.nextLine();
    int z = cad.length();
    char c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < z; i++) {
        c = (char) cad.charAt(i);
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' || c == ' ') { // MAYUSCULA->MANTIENE
                System.out.print(c);
            } else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' || c == ' ') { // PASAR A
                                                            // MAYUSCULA
                c = (char) (c - 'a' + 'A');
                System.out.print(c); 
            }

        } else if (i % 2 != 0) {
            if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' || c == ' ') { //MINUSCULA -> MANTIENE
                System.out.print(c);
            } else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' || c == ' ') { // PASAR A
                                                            // MINUSCULA
                c = (char) (c + 'a' - 'A');
                System.out.print(c);

            }
        }
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Es necesario usar _ASCII_?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Primera Parte

A la primera parte de tu pregunta, acerca de como alternar entre las mayusculas, podria mostrarte esto:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Escriba una cadena:");
        String cadena = teclado.nextLine();

        char caracter;
        int contadorCambio = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < cadena.length(); i++) {

            caracter = (char) cadena.charAt(i);

            if (caracter == ' ') {

                //Imprimimos el espacio en blanco
                System.out.print(caracter);

            } else {

                if (contadorCambio % 2 == 0) {

                    if (Character.isUpperCase(caracter)) {

                        // MAYUSCULA->MANTIENE
                        System.out.print(caracter);

                    } else if (Character.isLowerCase(caracter)) {

                        // PASAR A MAYUSCULA
                        caracter = (char) (caracter - 'a' + 'A');
                        System.out.print(caracter);

                    }

                } else {

                    if (Character.isLowerCase(caracter)) {

                        //MINUSCULA -> MANTIENE
                        System.out.print(caracter);

                    } else if (Character.isUpperCase(caracter)) {

                        // PASAR A MINUSCULA
                        caracter = (char) (caracter + 'a' - 'A');
                        System.out.print(caracter);

                    }

                }

                contadorCambio++;
            }

        }

    }
```

**Resultado:**

> Escriba una cadena:
>
> hola mundo
>
> HoLa MuNdO

He organizado un poco el codigo, y tambien no use el *ASCII* (Viejas Costumbres), en ese caso se puede reemplazar los condicionales con *ASCII* tal cual como lo tenias, aunque en mi caso, prefiero usar *isUpperCase()* y *isLowerCase()* ya que son funciones hechas a proposito para ahorrar al programador ese tipo de condiciones jugando con el codigo *ASCII*.

Evidentemente, si desear usar el codigo *ASCII* Solo cambia los condicionales, asi:

Character.isLowerCase(caracter) **POR** caracter >= 'a' && caracter <= 'a'
Character.isUpperCase(caracter) **POR** caracter >= 'A' && caracter <= 'Z'

### Segunda Parte

Respecto al problema que indicas (Dejar solo las iniciales como Mayusculas), esta seria mi solucion propuesta:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Escriba una cadena:");
    String cadena = teclado.nextLine();

    char caracter;
    boolean bandera = true;    // TRUE si se empieza una nueva palabra

    for (int i = 0; i < cadena.length(); i++) {

        caracter = (char) cadena.charAt(i);

        if (caracter == ' ') {

            //Imprimimos el espacio en blanco
            System.out.print(caracter);
            bandera = true;

        } else {

            if (bandera == true) {

                if (Character.isLowerCase(caracter)) {

                    // Pasar a Mayuscula
                    caracter = (char) (caracter - 'a' + 'A');
                    System.out.print(caracter);

                } else {

                    System.out.print(caracter);

                }

                bandera = false;
            } else {

                if (Character.isUpperCase(caracter)) {

                    // Pasar a Minuscula
                    caracter = (char) (caracter + 'a' - 'A');
                    System.out.print(caracter);

                } else {

                    System.out.print(caracter);

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

**Resultado:**

> Escriba una cadena:
>
> hOlA MUNDO esto ES uNa PruEba
>
> Hola Mundo Esto Es Una Prueba