# conversion de cadenas minusculas a mayusculas

Tags: java, netbeans

por favor me podrían ayudar con una conversión de cadena de minúsculas a mayúsculas utilizando vectores en una tabla en java usando NetBeans

Comment: Podrías adjuntar el código de lo que hasta ahora has intentado? quizás te encuentras cerca de la respuesta!

Answer (score -1):

lee lo siguiente puede ser que te se util:

[Pasar a mayusculas y minusculas una cadena java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46497/pasar-a-mayusculas-y-minusculas-una-cadena-java)

en caso contrario me avisas y te explico a mi manera

Comment: Buenas noches Helen la verda no me fue de mucha utilidad agradecería si me podrías ayudar de una forma distinta.

Comment: Se te agradece el apoyo pero responder con solo enlaces se considera de baja calidad, lee [answer] edita y mejora tu aporte